# Limit HTMLPurifier to accept specific tags

Tags: html, htmlpurifier

I am going to limit **[HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)** to only accept some specific HTML tags.

list of valid tags:

1. `<a>`
2. `<img>`
3. `<i>`
4. `<b>`

I read **[Configuration Documentation](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html)** and **[HTML Allowed Elements](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html)**

but there is not a good description and example.

if you have worked with this and limited some tags in HTML Purifier please give me an example.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, thanks everyone

**I found the answer:**
There's some example code here http://htmlpurifier.org/live/INSTALL

and to allow some specific tags:

```
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'b,a[href],i,img[src|alt]');
```

alt is also needed, as it is a required attribute by W3C spec.